# Swing Application with Spring Boot

Tags: java, swing, spring-boot, jframe

I have a swing UI application in spring boot and I am using Eclipse's window builder to prepare the UI. To start the application I am using

```
  ConfigurableApplicationContext context =
            new SpringApplicationBuilder(App.class).headless(false).run(args);
```

but I see the difference in the generated UI when run normally (with main class inside the UI class) and when run it with Spring boot.

with main class inside it

[image]

and when same code runs with spring boot, the same UI generated with border

[image]

Can someone please explain why there is a different UI in case of spring-boot and what is the best way to fix this ?

Comment: If there is a different UI, then you must be using a different LAF. Look at your code to see which LAF is used. The LAF needs to be set before any Swing components are created.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this, actually I was using LookandFeel "Nimbus" and when converted to "javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel", it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by using below statement in the code.

```
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check my example project with Spring Boot in Swing application:
https://github.com/DanielMichalski/spring-boot-swing-reservations

I'm using there:

```
import javax.swing.UIManager;

...

UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```